# Ширина и высота полей ввода в зависимости от содержимого

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator

Нужно задавать высоту QTextEdit в зависимости от кол-ва строк содержимого и если строк нет, то и высота нулевая.
Тоже самое и для QLineEdit, но для ширины.

Comment: Скорее всего это придется делать через перегрузку painEvent. При отрисовке смотрим текст в контроле и выставляем корректный FixedSize, главное чтобы не поехали layout'ы

Comment: @goldstar_labs, спасибо, хоть кто-то откликнулся. Думаю на MainWindow повесить скроллинг. Есть три поля: QTextEdit на всю ширину и переменная высота, в зависимости от содержимого, QLineEdit переменная ширина, в зависимости от содержимого, а всё остальное место по ширине должен занять второй QTextEdit.